# Why when I try to create a Datetime object with the input of the user as parameter says invalid date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, parameters, counter

So I am veeery new, and I am trying to create a counter app. So my problem is that when I am trying to pass the parameters :year, :month, etc, to a DateTime object it keeps telling me is an Invalid Date.

So the following is my controller class.

```
class CountersController < ApplicationController
def new
end

def create
  @counter= Counter.new(counter_params)

  @counter.save
  redirect_to @counter
end
private
    def counter_params
        @titulo=params[:titulo]
        @year=params[:year].to_i
        @month=params[:month].to_i
        @day=params[:day].to_i
        @hour=params[:hour].to_i
        @minute=params[:minute].to_i    
        d= DateTime.new(@year,@month,@day,@hour,@minute)
        c_p={"meta"=>d,"titulo"=>@titulo}
    end
```

end
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOPDy.png)

Comment: The date and time fields in `params` are capitalized but you're accessing them using lower case keys (which gives you `nil`s) and then you call `#to_i` on those `nil`s. The result is that you're saying `DateTime.new(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: Hi! So, I changed that and tried again, but it keeps showing me that error, got an Idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheel you can just use the [Rails date and time form helpers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#using-date-and-time-form-helpers):

```
<%= form_with(model: counter, local: true) do |form| %>
  ...   
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :meta %>
    <%= form.datetime_select :meta %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This creates some pretty strange params:

```
{"titelo"=>"", "meta(1i)"=>"2018", "meta(2i)"=>"10", "meta(3i)"=>"12", "meta(4i)"=>"18", "meta(5i)"=>"33"}
```

`meta(1i)` is for example the year. 1 is the part and `i` is the format (in this case an integer).

When you permit the key `:meta` Rails will also allow all the multiparameter keys as they are known.

```
(byebug) params.require(:counter).permit(:titelo, :meta)
<ActionController::Parameters {"titelo"=>"", "meta(1i)"=>"2018", "meta(2i)"=>"10", "meta(3i)"=>"12", "meta(4i)"=>"18", "meta(5i)"=>"42"} permitted: true>
```

And since ActiveRecord knows that the column is a datetime column it will assign the attribute correctly:

```
irb(main):005:0> Counter.new({"titelo"=>"", "meta(1i)"=>"2018", "meta(2i)"=>"10", "meta(3i)"=>"12", "meta(4i)"=>"18", "meta(5i)"=>"42"})
=> #<Counter id: nil, titelo: "", meta: "2018-10-12 18:42:00", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

So all you need in your controller is:

```
class CountersController < ApplicationController
  # ...

  # POST /counters
  # POST /counters.json
  def create
    @counter = Counter.new(counter_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @counter.save
        format.html { redirect_to @counter, notice: 'Counter was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @counter }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @counter.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # ...

  private 
  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def counter_params
      params.require(:counter).permit(:titelo, :meta)
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you! There are so many new things, I will go trough it slowly. Good Night/day. I forgot to ask, do you know why it doesnt work my code?

Comment: As mu is too short already pointed out you have named your inputs with capitals `Year` and you´re accessing the hash key `params[:year]` which is nil. Ruby is not case-insentive.